# Using Switch Statement to style/color multiple elements, through use of setAttribute() (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, switch-statement, weather-api, setattribute

I'm building a web page that detects your the weather forecast in your local area. However, to make it unique, I'm trying to make the web page change its colors on the interface. It would change the colors depending on which weather icon is in a weather api. (i.e. weath.weather[0]["icon"] ). I'm trying to make it run as fast as possible while at the same time make it more understandable. So I'm looking for an alternative method.

I decided to store the color changing function in a variable so it could be reused multiple times and so I could shorten the Switch statement. It contains a CSS string variable that can be reused. the string is the styling property for a setAttribute function:

```
var coloring = function(id, Text, Background) {
    var colorChange = "color: " + Text + "; background: " + Background + ";";
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style", colorChange);
};
```

This would be used to change colors of various elements/sections of the Dom by referring to their id. Here is the Dom:

```html
<body id="background">  
  <div id="header">
<h1>Local Weather Detector</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="location">
  <h5 id="locIntro">Today's weather from Location...</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
  <div id="temperature">
    <p><strong>Today, </strong>The temperature in your area is...
    <button id="tempSwap">
      </button></p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="weather">
    <p>- and the general forecast is...</p>
  </div>
    </div>
   <div id="copywrite"><h6> &#9400; Thomas Jackson</h6>
      <h6>(Project for Free Code Camp, Full Stack course)</h6></div>
</body>
```

I would get the icon data from the api then the switch statement would determine what colors need to be changed depending on which icon it is. Each Switch Case with the use of the coloring() function would change the Dom's colors to its own set colors:

```
$.getJSON(api, function(weath) {

  switch (weath.weather[0]["icon"]) {

      case "01d": //clear
        coloring("background", "#f1c40f", "#3498db");
        coloring("box", "#2980b9", "#ecf0f1");
        coloring("temp", "#c0392b", "");
        break;
      case "01d":
      case "03d":
      case "04d":
      case "50d": //cloud
        coloring("background", "#3498db", "#ecf0f1");
        coloring("header", "#f1c40f", "");
        coloring("box", "", "#2980b9");
        coloring("temp", "", "#3498db");
        break;
      case "02d": //cloudClear
        coloring("background", "c0392b", "#2980b9");
        coloring("header", "#f1c40f", "");
        coloring("box", "", "#ecf0f1");
        coloring("temp", "", "#2980b9");
        break;
      case "11d": //thunder
        coloring("background", "#c0392b", "#2980b9");
        coloring("header", "#f1c40f", "");
        coloring("box", "", "#f1c40f");
        coloring("temp", "", "#c0392b");
        break;
      case "13d": //snow
        coloring("background", "#ecf0f1", "#2980b9");
        coloring("header", "#34495e", "");
        coloring("box", "", "#a5f2f3");
        coloring("temp", "", "#34495e");
        break;
      case "03n":
      case "04n":
      case "50n": //cloudNight
        coloring("background", "#ecf0f1", "#7f8c8d");
        coloring("header", "#e74c3c", "");
        coloring("box", "#f1c40f", "#34495e");
        coloring("temp", "", "#2c3e50");
        break;
      case "09n":
      case "10n": //rainNight
        coloring("background", "#3498db", "#2c3e50");
        coloring("header", "#f1c40f", "");
        coloring("box", "#2980b9", "#95a5a6");
        coloring("temp", "#3498db", "#2980b9");
        break;
      case "11n": //thunderNight
        coloring("background", "#f1c40f", "#2c3e50");
        coloring("header", "#e74c3c", "");
        coloring("box", "#c0392b", "#f1c40f");
        coloring("temp", "", "#c0392b");
        break;
      case "13n": //snowNight
        coloring("background", "#f1c40f", "#2c3e50");
        coloring("header", "#a5f2f3", "");
        coloring("box", "#34495e", "#a5f2f3");
        coloring("temp", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f");
        break;}

}
```

If I am going about this the wrong way it would be good to know. My main goal here would be to make it more efficient and clear for other developers.

Comment: Since the code is already functional, I think this question is better suited in the code review stackexchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . There, people may give you better feedback.

Comment: thanks. Is there any way to move this over to StackExchange code review with out copying and pasting?

Comment: I dont think its possible to port it over there.

Comment: Oh my!! I cant believe how complicated the code indention is! I just want to post this..

Answer (score 0):

The way you're going about this isn't actually too far off from from what I'd call the "correct" way (there are usually more than one) – there's room for a couple of micro-optimizations and clarity enhancers though.

First, if you'd like to increase readability for other maintainers, I'd recommend storing the icon codes in named constants. A `case: "01d"` doesn't tell me anything about *what* the icon is, but this does:

```
var ICON_STORMY = "01d";
switch (weath.weather[0].icon) {
    case ICON_STORMY:
        ...
        break;
    ...
}
```

Second, your colouring function is used quite heavily so I would tighten that up a bit too – not by much, but maybe just so it could be called once instead of once for every `id`.

You could, for instance, write it like so:

```
function colorAll(elems) {
    elems.forEach(function (elem) {
        var colorChange = "color: " + elem.text + "; background: " + elem.background + ";";
        document.getElementById(elem.id).setAttribute("style", colorChange);
    });
}
```

...and then use that function like this:

```
colorAll([{ id: 'background', text: 'blah blah', background: '#666666' }, { ... }]);
```

...the idea being that it only needs to be called once if you pass all the info needed to complete a whole switch case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The very fact you said its not far off the "correct" way tells me I'm improving. I understand where you're coming from about using variables. But am I not better to use an object list instead of individual variables? I have a long list of icon choices in the form of an object list before. I got rid of it because i thought it would run faster I just wrote quotes next to each switch case. Which as you can see I did already. Thanks for your feedback anyway.

Comment: @TommyJackson Yep! You bet, that's definitely one of those "more ways than one" cases. Between a switch statement an object map, your performance gains are going to be negligible in differences no matter which you pick for a small handful of values. If you were looking to be especially clever (at the cost of some readability), you could even key the object by the icon codes like { '01d': { text: '...', etc } }.

Comment: But would I not be better to just add quotes next to each switch case? that would use less code and would explain what each is.

Comment: @TommyJackson That ultimately depends on your preference for labelling things (i.e. for other developers). You aren't penalized for assigning additional references; the differences in performance are completely mitigated by minification, garbage collection, and native level optimizations. If your goal is to simply "use less code", then strings with icon codes are fine – if your goal is to increase readability, then named constants perform that goal with no significant incurred performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

**Thinking in functional**

`switch` statement is useful, but it won't fit in with rest of functional code you write.It has side effects, chance of mutating state, side effects and mainly can't be composed with other functions

There should be almost always a default case in a switch statement.I am assuming.Case not registered if concerned value is not found in cases for
`weath.weather[0]["icon"]`. Let's look at the switch case we are handling

```
$.getJSON(api, function(weath) {

switch (weath.weather[0]["icon"]) {

  case "01d": //clear
    coloring("background", "#f1c40f", "#3498db");
    coloring("box", "#2980b9", "#ecf0f1");
    coloring("temp", "#c0392b", "");
    break;
  case "01d":
  case "03d":
  case "04d":
  case "50d": //cloud
    coloring("background", "#3498db", "#ecf0f1");
    coloring("header", "#f1c40f", "");
    coloring("box", "", "#2980b9");
    coloring("temp", "", "#3498db");
    break;
  default:
    console.log(`case is not registered`);
    break;
  }

}
```

If we convert into ternary the code looks like this. I am using ES6 arrow functions for better readability

```
$.getJSON(api,(weath) => {

    const icon = weath.weather[0].icon;

    // try to convert switch to if/else or ternary

    icon === '01d' ? coloring() : //coloring methods of 01d
    icon === '02d' ? coloring()   //coloring methods of 02d
                   : console.log('no case matched');

});
```

This repetitive code can be optimised with a function like following

```
const switchcase = (cases, defaultCase, key) => {

      if (key in cases) {
        return cases[key]
      } else {
        return defaultCase
      }
}
```

Apply the currying technique to above method and use ternary instead of traditional `if else`

```
const switchcase = cases => defaultCase => key =>
    key in cases ? cases[key] : defaultCase
```

Now the code can be optimized like following

```
$.getJSON(api, switchcase({
    '01d' : coloring1(),
    '02d' : coloring2()
    })(console.log('no case matched'))(weath.weather[0].icon)
);
```

There is a catch for this early version of `switchcase` as the entire object literal is evaluated before being passed to the `switchcase` function. This means `coloring1()` and `coloring2()` are both evaluated. This can be very dangerous.

If values in the object literal were functions, then they could be executed only when there is a matching case.

Code will change to

```
$.getJSON(api, switchcase({ 
    '01d':() => { coloring('x');coloring('...');},
    '02d':() => { coloring('y');coloring('...');}
    })(() => console.log('no cases matched'))(weath.weather[0].icon)
);
```

code with optimizations

```
$.getJSON(api, switchcase({
    01d:() => coloringClear(),
    03d:() => coloringCloud(),
    04d:() => coloringCloud(),
    50d:() => coloringCloud(),
    02d:() => coloringCloudClear(),
    11d:() => coloringThunder(),
    13d:() => coloringSnow(),
    03n:() => coloringCloudNight(),
    04n:() => coloringCloudNight(),
    50n:() => coloringCloudNight(),
    09n:() => coloringRainNight(),
    10n:() => coloringRainNight(),
    11n:() => coloringThunderNight(),
    13n:() => coloringSnowNight()
    })('Unknown')(weath.weather[0]["icon"])
);
```

Keep the object in a separate variable for better maintainability. Move all the coloring methods into one method as named above. write them as seperate functions

Hope will optimize the performance with above code